# Issue with tikz package in figure caption

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to compile

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    % Subfig 1
    \subfigure[$K=50$]{
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{1.png}}
    % Subfig 2
    \subfigure[$K=200$]{
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{2.png}}
    % Subfig 3
    \subfigure[$K=500$]{
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{3.png}}
    \caption{bla bla ({\color{magenta}\begin{tikzpicture}\draw [thick,dash pattern={on 7pt off 2pt on 1pt off 2pt}] (0,0) -- (0.75,0);\end{tikzpicture}}), bla bla.} \label{fig:UQ}
\end{figure}
```

But I have been receiving the following error:

> Undefined control sequence.
>
> < argument> {magenta}\begin {tikzpicture}\draw
> [thick,dash pattern={on 7p... l.37 ... the limited amount of the training data.}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
> \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the
> correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll
> forget about whatever was undefined.

When I remove

```
({\color{magenta}\begin{tikzpicture}\draw [thick,dash pattern={on 7pt off 2pt on 1pt off 2pt}] (0,0) -- (0.75,0);\end{tikzpicture}})
```

the error goes away. Is there any ways to keep this line there and fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `\listoffigures`, then try with the below `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    % Subfig 1
    \subfigure[$K=50$]{
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}}
    % Subfig 2
    \subfigure[$K=200$]{
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}}
    % Subfig 3
    \subfigure[$K=500$]{
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}}
    \caption[]{bla bla (\protect{\color{magenta}\begin{tikzpicture}\draw [thick,dash pattern={on 7pt off 2pt on 1pt off 2pt}] (0,0) -- (0.75,0);\end{tikzpicture}}), bla bla.} \label{fig:UQ}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Note that you didn't mention the `class` file name what you used, so I used standard `book` class file....